# Упростить условие if/elif

Tags: python

Как упростить данный код, ведь у меня таких `elif` еще много?

```
if data == "ENG_football_league":
    await teams_markup(teams = ENG_football_league)
       
elif data == "ENG_2_football_league":
    await teams_markup(teams = ENG_2_football_league)

elif data == "ESP_football_league":
    await teams_markup(teams = ESP_football_league)

elif data == "ESP_2_football_league":
    await teams_markup(teams = ESP_2_football_league)
...
```

Answer (score 11):

Одной из возможных способов упростить данный код будет использование словаря, сопоставляющего строку в переменной data со списком команд. Например, можно создать словарь league_teams следующего вида:

```py
league_teams = {
    "ENG_football_league": ENG_football_league,
    "ENG_2_football_league": ENG_2_football_league,
    "ESP_football_league": ESP_football_league,
    "ESP_2_football_league": ESP_2_football_league,
}
```

Тогда код можно будет заменить следующим образом:

```py
teams = league_teams.get(data)
if teams is not None:
    await teams_markup(teams=teams)
```

Comment: Условие в данном случае можно сократить до `if teams:` по идее